# Sqlite Android RawQuery selectargs

Tags: android, sqlite

The second Parameter of Rawquery seems not to work.
My String Array looks like this:

```
String selec1 = "pd_infochar2";
String selec2 = "pd_infochar3";
String selec3 = "pd_infochar4";
String selec4 = "pd_infochar5";
String[] argswhere = new String[] {selec1,
                selec2, selec3, selec4};
```

My query looks like this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM plant_data WHERE ((pd_infochar2=?) AND (pd_infochar3=?) AND (pd_infochar4=?) AND (pd_infochar5=?))";
```

And now i create the Cursor.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, argswhere);
```

I read similar questions & answers already, but for me it looks like i have done everything right.
When i use the above Code no line will be returned. If i set the second parameter of Rawquery to null and in the query i replace the ? with the Parameters from the Rawquery String[] everything works. Whats wrong?

Comment: Tip: The parentheses are **completely useless**.

Comment: What is the use of having `WHERE pd_infocharX = 'pd_infocharX'`?

Comment: Right, the parentheses are useless, i just tried that too ^^

Comment: The use of that is the following. Sometimes i have Values for these fields, sometimes not. So when i got no value it stays pd_infocharX and this is always true, when i have a value it searches the values.
Ah thanks for ur question.. i think i have it now.. when its a Value it should be a String for SQL, when not it should not be a string, thats the point

Comment: So... It should be a String or `NULL`. (NULL **is not** a string). OR, if the values are numeric, then Integer (or Real) or NULL. Just handle the NULL properly, since `it is a wild animal`.

Comment: But the problem is that selec1 could be null & selec2 could have a value. So i need something that stays there when theres no value. I dont have this the AND's will cause that i get nothing returned

Comment: You can compare NULL values, though. http://greladesign.com/blog/2011/04/10/sqlite-compare-null-values/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that pd_infochar2,pd_infochar3,pd_infochar4 and pd_infochar5 are fields in the database. If i add them as a String Array to the rawquery statement, the rawquery statement put ' around each String.

```
Wanted:
Select plant_id
From plants
Where pd_infochar2 = pd_infochar2

Real Output:
Select plant_id
From plants
Where pd_infochar2 = 'pd_infochar2'
```

To solve the Problem just add null as a second parameter to RawQuery & put the where statement directly in the query-String.